# ios echo cancellation on audio bitstream for voip

Tags: iphone, ios, sip, voip, audio-streaming

I'm developing a ios voip application. The quality of the call is quite sub-standard due to ambient noise when I make a call. The noise comes through the app.

I need help understanding which ios frameworks / libs to use to help me with ambient / echo cancellation for **streaming audio** -- the raw bitstream. I read parts of the multimedia framework stuff on ios but there's very little information on audio streams, most of those docs focus on audio files.

Can I make use of the standard ios audio libraries to cancel ambient noise during a voip call? How are the standard ios libs different from the Speeq library?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting called kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingQuality that you can set to adjust the level of suppression to apply to the Audio Units.    Here is the link to Apple's article. [Technical Q&A QA1683](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#qa/qa1683/_index.html)

Comment: The technical note shows a default value set at 127 for iphone 4+.  I'm testing on an iphone 4s so I'm assuming I'm getting the highest quality canceler. But it turns out the quality is still very bad. When I use the default iphone call app, the quality is magnitudes better.

Comment: Note that the link is outdated. Here is the new one: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1683/_index.html